# Nested yarn arguments

Tags: command-line, scripting, command, yarnpkg

I have the following package.json with the following scripts.

```
{ 
    "scripts": {
         "run:a": "foo --devKey",
         "run:as": "yarn run:a --devKey"
    }
}
```

Knowing that the function `foo` expects `--devKey` value as an input.

How can i just pass the `--devKey` argument down to `"run:a"` from `"run:as"` through the command line with this command `yarn run:as --devKey <something>`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this? I can find anything about it.